# Function pointers in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

Are function pointers supported in Inno Setup?  I can't find anything in the documentation.  I know Delphi/Pascal supports them and as the Inno Setup scripting engine is based on it, I'm hoping it is supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did a little test and function pointers do work indeed. The following `[Code]` section compiles and works just fine:

```pascal
type
  TStrProc =  procedure (const AStr: String);

procedure Call(const AProc: TStrProc; const AStr: String);
begin
  AProc(AStr);
end;

procedure ShowStr(const AStr: String);
begin
  MsgBox(AStr, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Call(@ShowStr, 'Hello World!');
end;
```

BTW: Inno Setup uses [the Pascal Script engine from RemObjects](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx). Maybe you can find some more information there.